# Why the journalist said "he talks like Saint-Just"? What' the implication?

Tags: meaning-in-context, culture, implication

I understand that Saint-Just was a Jacobin leader during the French Revolution. But I wonder why the journalist compared the doctor to Saint-Just. Could anyone help please?

The context is:
The journalist is asking the doctor Rieux for information about the sanitary conditions in Arab.

Here is the sentence in the context:

> “I mean,” Rieux explained, “would you be allowed to publish an
>   unqualified condemnation of the present state of things?”
>
> “Unqualified? Well, no, I couldn’t go that far. But surely things
>   aren’t quite so bad as that?”
>
> “No,” Rieux said quietly, they weren’t so bad as that. He had put the
>   question solely to find out if Rambert could or couldn’t state the
>   facts without paltering with the truth. “I’ve no use for statements in
>   which something is kept back,” he added. “That is why I shall not
>   furnish information in support of yours.”
>
> The journalist smiled. “**You talk the language of Saint-Just**.”

*from  The Plague*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quote from the Wikipedia article about the man:
[Wikipedia "Saint-Just"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Antoine_de_Saint-Just)

"For his unyielding severity, later writers dubbed him the 'Angel of Death'."

It sounds as if the fellow was just a bit uncompromising.
But that's an English translation of Camus's "La peste", a French book, and the question has more to do with French culture than with English, I think.